# Problems with ndk-gdb - gdb.setup, putpkt, running PID

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have built a native library with ndk-build, and it is marked as debuggable in Android.mk. If I go into the cygwin shell and run

```
cd (PROJDIR)
ndk-gdb --start --verbose
```

I get the following:

```
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7b
Using default adb command: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
Using ADB flags: 
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: tiny.test2
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 15
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/tiny.test2/lib/gdbserver
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
Found data directory: '/data/data/tiny.test2'
Found first launchable activity: .Test2Activity
Launching activity: tiny.test2/.Test2Activity
## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n tiny.test2/.Test2Activity
Starting: Intent { cmp=tiny.test2/.Test2Activity }

## COMMAND: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb shell sleep 2
Found running PID: 0
ERROR: Could not extract PID of application on device/emulator.
       Weird, this probably means one of these:

         - The installed package does not match your current manifest.
         - The application process was terminated.

       Try using the --verbose option and look at its output for details.
```

It doesn't reach the gdb prompt for debugging. I tried launching it from Eclipse with a breakpoint in the .java file before the first C++ function call, and then while it was at the java breakpoint running ndk-gdb, and it successfully found running PID 1977, connected to the device through port 5039, and pulled libc.so from the device, but then got a swag of `Error while mapping shared library sections: libxxxx.so: No such file or directory`. The symbols are not found in `info sharedLibrary`.

I have added `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -ggdb -O0` to Android.mk under advice from another question, and removed the line from `$(NDK_PATH)/build/core/build-binary.mk` that strips the extras from the .so file.

If anyone knows the likely cause of these errors, please help.

Thanks

EDIT: ndk-gdb tells me 'This GDB was configured as "--host-i586-mingw32msvc --target=arm-elf-linux"' immediately before '(no debugging symbols found)'

Does this mean anything?

EDIT2: running `share` from gdb returns a list of `Symbol file not found`s for all the .so files. This looks to me like I haven't generated the symbol files properly, or they're not included in the search path. Where should they be set?

EDIT3: Turns out I had missed an important line in the ndk-gdb doc -

```
   "The GDB prompt will be preceded by a long list of error messages,
   where gdb complains that it cannot find various system libraries
   (e.g. libc.so, libstdc++.so, liblog.so, libcutils.so, etc...)

   This is normal, because there are no symbol/debug versions of
   these libraries corresponding to your target device on your
   development machine. You can safely ignore these messages."
```

This doesn't solve the problem, but it helps to know that those aren't errors.

Comment: +1 for EDIT3, I had missed that too :)

Answer (score 0):

do u have the env ANDROID_NDK_ROOT? that MUST like as /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7* under Windows.
Try to add DNK_DEBUG=1 to compile..
like: ndk-build DNK_DEBUG=1 -B V=1

Also, make sure u have both gdbserver and gdb.set under libs/$(Target-ABI)/

hope can help u.

Comment: `echo $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7c/`

re-compiled with ndk-build DNK_DEBUG=1 -B V=1, built with no errors. checked contents of libs/armeabi. ndk-gdb gives same output, can't find debugging symbols.

Comment: as you can see in the question, gdb can find gdbserver, and gdb.setup, but using the --start argument it doesn't find a PID. If the application is already started, it finds a valid PID, but not the debugging symbols in the shared libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: "...it is marked as debuggable in Android.mk..." Do u add debuggable in AndroidManifest.xml? like as <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

Comment: yes it is...

using the simple example hello-jni, it lets me load the program fine, but the 'sharedLibrary' command says no symbols found. It gives warnings that it can't set breakpoints, but it does recognise the function label and line number.

my more complex library won't even get that far.

Comment: i see, your package name is tiny.test2, mm, maybe it's too short for the older NDK revision(bug), try change it more than 4, like as com.android.tiny.test2. please try again. ;>

Comment: i tried changing the package name, didn't help. The whole issue seems to stem from the error 
    `C:/Users/Chris/workspace/Test2/obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup:4: Error in sourced command file:
    Remote communication error: Bad file descriptor.`
Line 4 in gdb.setup is blank, line 3 is the `directory` line. Any idea what can get screwed up here?

Comment: gdb.setup format: line 1: set so lib search path, line 2: directory, line 3: file obj/local/armeabi/app_process(IMPORTANT!), line 4: target remote. Do u have line 3 and app_process file under obj/local/armeabi/?(same directory as gdb.setup)

Comment: Contents of gdb.setup (located in $PROJDIR/obj/local/armeabi/)

    `set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi

    directory C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include C:/Android/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include jni

    file C:/Users/Chris/workspace2/Test2/obj/local/armeabi/app_process
    target remote :5039`
It has full paths because I changed the gdbinit.setup, thinking there may be an issue with relative paths. app_process is also in $PROJDIR/obj/local/armeabi

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure how to format new lines in these comments. does gdb consider blank lines in its line numbering? I have line1 set solib, line 2 blank, line 3 directory, line 4 blank, line 5 file, line 6 target remote

Comment: "Launching activity: tiny.test2/.Test2Activity
adb shell am start -n tiny.test2/.Test2Activity
Starting: Intent { cmp=tiny.test2/.Test2Activity }
adb shell sleep 2
Found running PID: 0"                                                                                                               ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Can application run successful WITHOUT debug? maybe gdb.setup is correct. the problem is, your application activity(Test2Activity) NOT started. so there is NO process(PID) gdb can attach.

Comment: if the app process crash immediately before gdb process attached it.gdb'll NOT found any PID.  Maybe you can sleep some seconds or add a breakpoint in Test2Activity onCreate() method(in Java code).so that, your gdb process will attach the app process.  hope it's useful...

Comment: the only way I could get it to get this far was by having a breakpoint in the Java code, launching the application from Eclipse in debug mode, then starting gdb. I did think it odd that it would give PID 0 but if the application isn't running then it gives an error about not finding the PID, so I figured maybe 0 is correct.

Comment: yes, PID is 0 because NOT found app process. so U can add a breakpoint in the Java code. then debug and stop there.(Don't continue), then start gdb with "ndk-gdb --verbose"(WITHOUT --start), gdb will attach the paused app process. Enter gdb console. you can add some breakpoints in c code. then continue breakpoint in Java code. hope it's useful.

Comment: it's useful in that it confirms what I thought. It's not useful in that that is exactly what I have been doing, which hasn't been working. It won't let me do anything until I load the lib with the 'file' command, then I can set breakpoints, but gdb doesn't know where in code i am, `where` returns `??` and `info shared` returns no symbols